# On collinear points

Tags: geometry

Take three disjoint circles $D, E, F$ (of different radius, although the property remains valid if not). Let $P, Q, R$ be the intersection points of the tangents common to $D$ and $E$, to $D$ and $F$ and to $E$ and $F$ respectively. Show that the points $P,Q, R$ are located on the same straight line.

(*All careful drawing of three disjoint circles and the corresponding tangents will be a verification of this property but it is asked for a mathematical proof*).

[image]

Comment: Can we use Desargues' theorem for this? If we draw a line through the points where the tangent lines intersect on either side of each circle, the three lines you get appear to intersect at a common point $p$. We could then apply Desargues', giving that $P,Q,R$ are collinear.

Comment: If I am not wrong Desargue's theorem start with two given triangles and with this problem the starting point is three given disjoints circles. Besides, the lines involved in Desargue's are not tangents of circumcircles (wait, yes with incircles but the involved lines could cut circles). The problem is that a third triangle would give two distincts applications of Desargue's and a third circle for our problem is of arbitrary position. I don't believe what you wonder works but it would be possible maybe. Sorry for bad English.